# How early to arrive for domestic flight at O'Hare airport?

Tags: airports, united-airlines, chicago

I have a United Airlines domestic flight from O'Hare airport at 8pm (Thursday in September if it matters) and I want to know how early I need to arrive. I need to check luggage and also I think with Basic Economy ticket I can't check in online. Is two hours enough or should I arrive three hours before the flight?

Comment: What makes you think you can't check in online with Basic Economy?  Online check-in saves money for the airline so I'd be really surprised if they restrict it in any way.

Comment: @NateEldredge: https://thepointsguy.com/2017/06/yet-another-reason-not-to-book-united-basic-economy/

Comment: That says it only applies to people who are not checking luggage.  You say you are checking luggage.  Of course, you will need to go to the counter to drop off your checked luggage, but you can still check in online for the flight and print your boarding pass at home.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Yes, that's right but some of us won't have any luggage to check

Comment: You'll be traveling around rush hour in Chicago, so the main issue is not so much how early you need to get to the airport;  it's how early you need to leave to ensure that you don't miss your flight due to traffic on the Kennedy Expressway.

Comment: If you are checking a bag and **pay the fee online**, you can check-in online.  If you are *not* checking a bag and *not* bringing on a full-size carry-on, you *cannot* check-in online.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: I plan to take the L train to the airport so I guess I won't be affected by traffic will I ?

Comment: @Johns-305: Where can I pay the fee online?

Comment: Yeah, I'd probably recommend the Blue Line, particularly if you don't have a lot of luggage.

Comment: @Giorgi Sorry, I'm not to sure what you're asking.  united.com is where  you pay regardless of what stage of the transaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two hours is sufficient.  I've always done two hours for domestic and maybe two and half for international.

Answer (score 0):

It's personal preference you need to think about the time of your flight, the day of your flight. It may be leaving off time so it would be busy but I recommend you at least have 1 hour and 45 mins of spare time and get to the airport 3 hours before your flight